# Turn off MemCachedClient logging in play framework 2

Tags: java, playframework, spymemcached

I am using a MemCachedClient in play framework2 and I get INFO message such as these:

```
2014-06-12 11:37:45.513 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Added {QA sa=/127.0.0.1:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue
2014-06-12 11:37:45.516 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@1ab07e8
```

I want to turn them off. How can I achieve it in play framework2

Comment: No it didn't work. Thanks. I will be putting the solution in answers which did work.

Answer (score 2):

Putting the following lines of code before creating the `MemcachedClient` object did the trick for me.

```
System.setProperty("net.spy.log.LoggerImpl", "net.spy.memcached.compat.log.SunLogger");
Logger.getLogger("net.spy.memcached").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
```

Comment: Thanks! In my case I used `net.spy.memcached.compat.log.SLF4JLogger`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set `logger.net.spy.memcached=OFF` in your `application.conf`. Or perhaps just bump it up to something higher like `WARN` or `ERROR`.

Source: [Play - SettingsLogger](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SettingsLogger)